# Synchronizing asynchronous events

Tags: c#, events, asynchronous, .net-4.5

I have a class that receives standard .Net events from an external class.
These events have an address property (in addition to a lot of other properties, of course) that I can use to synchronize my events, so that I should be able to create a method to Get something, wait for the correct event, then return the data from the event in the Get method.

However, I'm fairly new to synchronization in C# and was hoping any of you could help me out. Below is somewhat pseudo code for what I want to accomplish:

1. Someone calls `DoAsynchronousToSynchronousCall`
2. That method waits until an event have been received with the same address (or until it times out)
3. The event checks against all current requests. If it finds a request with the same address, let `DoAsynchronousToSynchronousCall` know the reply has arrived
4. `DoAsynchronousCall` gets (or retrieves) the reply and returns it to the caller

---

```
public class MyMessage
{
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Data { get; set; }
}

public Main
{
    externalClass.MessageReceived += MessageReceived;
}

public void MessageReceived(MyMessage message)
{
    MyMessage request = _requestQueue.FirstOrDefault(m => m.Address = message.Address);
    if (request != null)
    {
        // Do something to let DoAsynchronousToSynchronousCall() know the reply has arrived
    }
}

private List<MyMessage> _requestQueue = new List<MyMessage>();
public MyMessage DoAsynchronousToSynchronousCall(MyMessage message)
{
    _requestQueue.Add(message);
    externalClass.Send(message);

    // Do something to wait for a reply (as checked for above)
    MyMessage reply = WaitForCorrectReply(timeout: 10000);
    return reply;
}
```

I feel like I'm missing an opportunity to use `async` and `await` (yet I don't know how), and I hope you're able to understand what I'm trying to accomplish based on the information above.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You're probably looking for [`ManualResetEvent`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which functions as a "toggle" of sorts to switch between thread-blocking and non-blocking behavior. The `DoAsynchronousToSynchronousCall` would `Reset` and then `WaitOne(int timeoutMilliseconds)` the event to block the thread, and the thing checking for the correct reply arrived would do the `Set` call to let the thread continue on its way if the correct thing arrived.

Comment: Yes, but how would that handle if multiple callers call `DoAsynchronousToSynchronous`? Wouldn't just one `ManualResetEvent` be good for only one caller?

Comment: You add the reset event to `MyMessage` so each one gets its own copy

Comment: Thanks to @ScottChamberlain's clarification I managed to get it to work with `ManualResetEvent` :)

Answer (score 1):

You really can't have multiple calls on the fly and have synchronous responses. If you want synchronous responses for multiple calls then you need to do the calls synchronously too.

I would look at using Microsoft's Reactive Extensions (NuGet "Rx-Main") to make what you're doing as simple as possible. Rx lets you turn events into streams of values that you can query against.

Here's what I would do.

I would first define a stream of the received messages as `IObservable<MyMessage> receivedMessages` like this:

```
receivedMessages =
    Observable
        .FromEvent<MessageReceivedHandler, MyMessage>(
            h => externalClass.MessageReceived += h,
            h => externalClass.MessageReceived -= h);
```

(You didn't provide a class def so I've called the event delegate `MessageReceivedHandler`.)

Now you can redefine `DoAsynchronousToSynchronousCall` as:

```
public IObservable<MyMessage> DoAsynchronousCall(MyMessage message)
{
    return Observable.Create<MyMessage>(o =>
    {
        IObservable<MyMessage> result =
            receivedMessages
                .Where(m => m.Address == message.Address)
                .Take(1);

        IObservable<MyMessage> timeout =
            Observable
                .Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10.0))
                .Select(x => (MyMessage)null);

        IDisposable subscription =
            Observable
                .Amb(result, timeout)
                .Subscribe(o);

        externalClass.Send(message);

        return subscription;
    });
}
```

The `result` observable is the `receivedMessages` filtered for the current `message.Address`.

The `timeout` observable is a default value to return if the call takes longer than `TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10.0)` to complete.

Finally the `subscription` uses `Observable.Amb(...)` to determine which of `result` or `timeout` produces a value first and subscribes to that result.

So now to call this you can do this:

```
DoAsynchronousCall(new MyMessage() { Address = "Foo", Data = "Bar" })
    .Subscribe(response => Console.WriteLine(response.Data));
```

So, if I make a simple definition of `ExternalClass` like this:

```
public class ExternalClass
{
    public event MessageReceivedHandler MessageReceived;
    public void Send(MyMessage message)
    {
        this.MessageReceived(new MyMessage()
        {
            Address = message.Address,
            Data = message.Data + "!"
        });
    }
}
```

...I get the result `Bar!` printed on the console.

If you have a whole bunch of messages that you want to process you can do this:

```
var messagesToSend = new List<MyMessage>();

/* populate `messagesToSend` */

var query =
    from message in messagesToSend.ToObservable()
    from response in DoAsynchronousCall(message)
    select new
    {
        message,
        response
    };

query
    .Subscribe(x =>
    {
        /* Do something with each correctly paired
            `x.message` & `x.response`
        */
    });
```